# geth account list returns accounts but eth.accounts does not

Tags: go-ethereum, accounts, keystore

I had my ethereum node on one server. I needed to migrate the accounts and all to another server (due to the huge size of blockchain). I started new ethereum node on another server. To copy my accounts, I copied the `keystore` folder from one server to other.

Now my node on new server is fully synced but when in `geth console` I type `eth.accounts`, it returns an empty array. However, if I check by `geth account list`, it displays me list of all accounts. Also on `eth.coinbase` returns me one of my accounts. What's going wrong?

I have etheres as well as custom token in my account. Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 5):

I had to explicitly set the location of my `keystore` directory to get `eth.accounts` to show the right thing.

What I did was:

```
geth --light --keystore ~/.ethereum/keystore console
```

and then typing `eth.accounts` showed me a non-null array.

Very strangely, it seems this is a limited-time thing - I now no longer need to specify `--keystore <location>` anymore.

Should it help others, I had just done `geth account import` before `eth.accounts` stopped working as expected.

Comment: Had the same issue despite having the right datadir location (```geth --help``` shows the current datadir). Providing ```--keystore``` option also worked for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what was causing the problem. But copying only the address files from old keystore to new keystore instead of replacing new keystore folder with old one solved the problem.
It seems weird to me yet it solved the problem. Anyone having reson for this is welcome to edit the answer.